# swift:receive AWS id_token after sending facebook current token to AWS Cognito?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to send the facebook access token to the AWS Cognito and then receive an authorization token which can further be sent as an Authorization header in HTTP Put request.
However, I always get "unauthorized" response from the AWS end point.

When I try to print :

```
    credentialsProvider.credentials().continueOnSuccessWith(executor: AWSExecutor.default()) { (task) -> Any? in
            print(task.error)
            return true
        }
```

I get the following output:

```
Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSJSONBuilderErrorDomain Code=4 "serialized object is neither a valid json Object nor NSData object: {
    IdentityPoolId = "******";
    Logins =     {
        "graph.facebook.com" = "<FBSDKAccessToken: *******>";
    };
}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=serialized object is neither a valid json Object nor NSData object: {
    IdentityPoolId = "*****+*";
    Logins =     {
        "graph.facebook.com" = "<FBSDKAccessToken: ******>";
    };
}})
```

This is my code:

```
import AWSCognito
class FacebookProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {
    func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
        if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current() {
            return AWSTask(result: [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook:token])
        }
        return AWSTask(error:NSError(domain: "Facebook Login", code: -1 , userInfo: ["Facebook" : "No current Facebook access token"]))
    }
}

class API {
..............

public func putOrder(when fbLogin: Bool, _ order: Order, onSuccess: @escaping(JSON) -> Void,
                         on Failure: @escaping(Error)-> Void) {
        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .EUCentral1 ,
                                                                identityPoolId:"*****", identityProviderManager:FacebookProvider())
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.EUCentral1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    let url = "\(serverURL)\(API.loginOrderPath)"
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = API.apiMethodPut
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.setValue("\(credentialsProvider.credentials())", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    do {
        var json: JSON
        json = ["companyId": order.companyId, "drinks": order.drinksId, "payment": order.payment, "tip": order.tip]
        urlRequest.httpBody = try json.rawData()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                Failure(error!)
            } else {
                if let response = try? JSON(data: data!) {
                    onSuccess(response)
                } else {
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    } catch _ {
    }
}
```

}

Expected Result: JSON response from the AWS Server 
Actual Result : unauthorised

Comment: can you add the code where you create the Cognito Credentials Provider to the question ?

Comment: I haven't created any. this is my only code for that.

Comment: well, the `credentialsProvider` variable *has been* created and initialized somewhere, hasn't it ?

Comment: and can you share the code for that ?  It is difficult to help without having a look at your code.

Comment: I just reformatted my question,  The code is more clear in the question now. . Its initialised in API class -- inside putOrder(..) method.

Comment: what is the endpoint you are trying to access ?  API Gateway ?  GraphQL ?  Other ?  The main raison of the failure is because credentialsProvider.credentials() can not be serialized to JSON.  Even if it would, it would fail because I don't know any service accepting a raw cognito credentials as authentication header.  If I know which service you are trying to access, I will be able to show you how to correctly pass the credentials

Comment: api gateway with a cognito authorizer. we dont want to have cognito credentials, but `access_token` and `id_token` of a cognito userpool

Comment: The flow that I want to achieve is : 1) log in with Facebook and get a fb token 
2) use this Facebook token and send it to aws cognito
3) receive a cognito id token
4)use this token as „Authorization“ header when you send the  PUT req

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your are receiving an `unauthorized` response from API Gateway is double :

1. `credentialsProvider.credentials()` is not serialized to JSON and can not be "as is" for the authorization headers.
2. Looks like you are trying to manually call API Gateway, by managing your self the low level details of the URL Request.  I don't see code to add a signature to the request.  All authenticated API Gateway requests must be signed (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/) and the Authorization header must contain the credentials used to compute the signature.

Managing the low level details of AWS Signature is not trivial.  You should not write code to do that but use the [AWS iOS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ios/index.html#lang/en_us) instead.  In particular, if you're trying to call API Gateway with Cognito User Pool authorisation, have a look at this example : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-ios-swift.html.

The API Gateway console will generate the client side code required to run this example (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/genearte-ios-sdk-of-an-api.html)

This should remove a lot of boiler plate from your code, making it easier to read and to maintain.

The flow posted in your comment above, the iOS SDK will take care of 2/ 3/ and 4/ steps for you - automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does this work for identity pools or user pools?

Comment: both.  identity pools allows to use standard IAM access control (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html) and Cognito User Pools are documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. How can I Send the Facebook authentication token I  received from signing in with Facebook to the Amazon Cognito identity pool as an authorization header

Comment: Also, does this only work with hosted UI or a can also work on facebook login button added explicitly?

Comment: Cognito ID Pool has no hosted GUI.  Hosted GUI is for Cognito User Pool only.

Comment: To pass your Facebook OAuth token to Cognito Identity Pool, follow this doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html It has a step by step guide and code sample in Swift